# How to fetch the data from DAO to Action class using Structs2?

Tags: java

How can I fetch the table to my action class? When onclicking the button this function happens.

This is my action class:

```
public class Action {
    ActionVO avo = new ActionVO();
    ActoinForm af = new ActionFrom();
    public string loaddata() {
        if (af == null) {
            PropertyUtils.copyProperties(ActionVO, ActionForm);
            HashMap hmInput = new HashMap();
            hmInput.put(APPCONSTANT.WORKFLOW_ID, APPCONSTANT.REQ_CODE);
            hmInput.put(APPCONSTANT.INPUT_CRETERIA, avo);
            rvo.execute(hmInput);
            af.setSummaryList((Arraylist) rvo.getResultList());
            request.setAttribute("setSummaryList", af.getSummaryList());
            request.getSession().setAttribute("", ActionVO.getSummaryList());
            return success;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Structs2`... makes sense